# VirtualBox's SEAMLESS MODE and AUTO RESIZE GUEST options DISABLED

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I'm using virtualbox with:

- *HOST*: Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit
- *GUEST*:  Windows XP (pre SP1)

**NOTES**

1. I am on Windows XP pre-SP1. But currently updating to SP1 (then testing this problem) then updating to SP4 (or 3, whichever is the last one)
2. I installed the **Guest Additions**. But they *seem* to be **not working** because:

   1. Cipboard **Sharing** & Drag & Drop **not working**.  Clipboard sharing (bidirectional) and Drag & Drop (bidirection) are enabled yet  NEITHER is working. So I'm kinda wondering if Guest Additions is really installed.
   2. **Networking** is **not** working (I have Guest set to default: NAT
3. Curiously, I was browsing the Guest Additions virtual "CD" and it 
   had nothing in the \64-bit folder but readme.txt with a note that
   the Guest Addition Windows Drivers have been moved to save space and
   you can extract them with .  I Did that (and got the
   confirmation that *Oracle...extensions successfully extracted to E:\
   Drivers" extracted to the Windows Drive (D)
4. Guest Config Details

[image]
[image]

2. The Guest OS is on the Guest's E: drive not C:\
3. I have confirmed I have enough video memory assigned in Guest (64 MB) for seamless model

Comment: I'm a little confused... You say "Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit HOST and Windows 7 Home running as Guest" but then "Windows XP pre-SP1", and your screen shots show and XP Pro VM. So is your actually guest XP Pro, or 7 Home?

Comment: There also seems to be a couple half-sentences in your question: "Seamless mode (and" And what?  "you can extract them with . I Did that"  With what?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Windows XP SP2 and that fixed it.